# In Python, transform a nested string list into another arrangement

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-itertools

Curious if there was a fancy way of transforming this array:

```
[[a0],
[b0, b1],
[c0, c1],
[d0, d1],
[e0],
[f0],
[g0]]
```

into this array:

```
[["", b0, c0, d0, "", "", ""],
 [a0, b1, c1, d1, e0, f0, g0]]
```

i.e. Matrix manipulation, zip, etc?
The input list is a list of column headers. If there are multiple items in a column header, it is multi-lined header.
The output list is transformed so that it can be printed.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

lst = [["a0"], ["b0", "b1"], ["c0", "c1"], ["d0", "d1"], ["e0"], ["f0"], ["g0"]]

out = list(map(list, zip_longest(*(v[::-1] for v in lst), fillvalue="")))[::-1]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[['', 'b0', 'c0', 'd0', '', '', ''], ['a0', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e0', 'f0', 'g0']]
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I stepped through each section to understand what it was doing. Thanks!

Comment: `zip_longest` of course also happily accepts iterators, so you could give it `map(reversed, lst)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach would be to unpack each sub-list into an item on the right and the rest of the items of the left with the star operator, so you can replace a missing left item with an empty string by testing the if the list on the left is empty:

```
list(zip(*((a or ['']) + [b] for *a, b in lst)))
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/Lxsvn7

Answer (score 0):

Padding for `zip`:

```py
lst = [["a0"], ["b0", "b1"], ["c0", "c1"], ["d0", "d1"], ["e0"], ["f0"], ["g0"]]

m = max(map(len, lst))
out = list(map(list, zip(*(
    [""] * (m - len(v)) + v
    for v in lst
))))

print(out)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY87DsIwEER7n2Lkyg6OFDoaTmKlyBcsxY6VOBFwFZo0cBBuwW3YJGab2afVzGqeb38P194ty2sKbXr6frox4AyteZHxXEHzMuMKvDzuVG1URao3qiM10dFGvZDmjFnKs8VN2MKLrnEK9EJK1k_ro86MYb_QovAwXiSCgUZzniOBsEhBNjFLiQPm7db2A2YYt0YxScOYH4wLgkLl3iQW-hf7AQ)